# Xamarin Bottom Bar Gets Lost

Tags: xamarin

I have a listview, a toolbar and a bottom nav bar. Toolbar is aligned to top while nav bar is aligned to bottom. Its working well unless i add items to listview. After adding 5 items, the bottom bar disappears. Cant i align the bot bar like the toolbar so it just stays still ?

Activity's axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <include
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   layout="@layout/toolbar" />

  <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listv_sepet" />
     <include
   android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
   layout="@layout/toolbar_bot"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>     

 </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Bottom Toolbar axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar                               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" 
/>
```

Thanks in the advance.

Comment: Add your XAML or AXML layout to the question

Comment: Allright its done

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you wrap the height of the ListView and don't tell it to be above the bottom Toolbar.

This can easily be fixed by:

1. un-nesting your layout as it is not really necessary in this case to do any nesting.
2. tell the ListView to be below the top Toolbar and above the bottom Toolbar

So something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:id="@+id/listv_sepet" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_bot"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>     
</RelativeLayout>
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Nope it did not fix it. The bottom bar is not even visible.

Comment: Its probably because of we assign listview's height to match parent? So it just assigns it to full screen and this leaves our bottom bar out of the screen?

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using an include in your layout you can set the footer (and header) in code when binding to the listview by using the `AddHeaderView` and `AddFooterView` methods

For example:

```
        listView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.mylistView);
        View headerView = View.Inflate(Activity, Resource.Layout.ListHeader, null);
        listView.AddHeaderView(headerView);
```